# Bluez on DBus: Connection is not allowed / Name already in use

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I am writing a [BLE library for JavaScript](https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/) and after I restarted my computer Bluez stopped working

When I write `bluetoothd -n` I get this:

```
➜  bluetoothd -n
bluetoothd[2728]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.75" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
bluetoothd[2728]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

with `sudo` I get this:

```
➜  sudo bluetoothd -n
bluetoothd[2751]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[2751]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

`service bluetooth status` gets me

```
➜   service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-10-26 13:04:51 CEST; 27min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 772 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─772 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Okt 26 13:04:50 tomato systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Okt 26 13:04:51 tomato bluetoothd[772]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Okt 26 13:04:51 tomato bluetoothd[772]: Starting SDP server
Okt 26 13:04:51 tomato bluetoothd[772]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Okt 26 13:04:51 tomato systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Okt 26 13:04:56 tomato bluetoothd[772]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Okt 26 13:04:56 tomato bluetoothd[772]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

This is my

[/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf](https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/168e759cd91fede30e15a2b29b5da48a)

as a gist

The computer I am developing on is a with built in bluetooth, but because I have seen this question a lot, here is my output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
➜  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85f2]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:17ea Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am pretty baffled with what I can do.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Did you find a solution?

Comment: It did work eventually but I did so many things I can't remember what this was, sorry :( . Stupid me did not post the solution then :/

Comment: No worries - it fixed itself magically over the weekend anyway! Just going to pretend it never happened...

Comment: Weird but ok haha, bluez seems kind of fragile :D